# Is there a difference between modeling Path Dependence and using a Lagged Dependent Variable?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, dynamic-regression, path-model

I am modeling the choice of transport mode of a series of questionnaire respondents at year `y`. So far, I've resorted on modeling the choice as a function of a series of IVs plus their choices at year `y-15`. As far as I undetstand, this is a lagged dependent variable model.

In looking at related work, I see references to the need to account for Path Dependence. It seems that this is a common practice in political sciences in particular. However, I cannot understand if there is a difference between accounting for Path Dependence and what I am already doing. Would anyone be able to clarify that?

Comment: Including Lags of the dependent variable in the regressors, is one way of incorporating / accounting for Path Dependence in a model, indeed. But there may be others.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos: thanks for the clarification. Can you think of a reference that puts these two in the same framework? And wouldn't you prefer to post your comment as an answer, so that we can upvote it or choose it as best answer?

Comment: My comment is not up to standards for an answer. If I find something more to contribute, I will return with an answer proper.